# MySQL export command doesn't output anything

Tags: mysql, linux, export

I'm trying to export a MySQL database with a command I use quite often

```
mysql --user=root --database=dbname > myfile.sql
```

It starts working. Usually I check on the status by opening another terminal and checking the output file size. Generally it grows in size quite quickly until it finishes. Now it's 0b large and not growing.

I let the mysql process run for a while before I cancelled it using CTRL+C. The output sql file now contains only the words "CTRL-C -- exit!"

Any idea what I might be doing wrong this time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) not `mysql` (which is the command-line client).

Comment: That doesn't really explain why it usually works fine, but now does nothing. Is there a logfile somewhere I could check?

Comment: I think you must just be mistaken here - I think you must usually type 'mysqldump' not 'mysql'. I've never seen just 'mysql' work like that. (But then I'm not a complete guru here, I've always used mysqldump.)

Comment: I've always used mysql, but perhaps this functionality has been deprecated and removed. Thanks for your answer